# What song is playing 12 minutes into episode 13 of Code Geass R1?

Tags: music, code-geass

What song is playing 12 minutes into episode 13 in the first season of *Code Geass*?

Answer (score 2):

The song is titled **Stories**, sung by Hitomi Kuroishi (黒石ひとみ).

More details about it is here:
http://codegeass.wikia.com/wiki/Stories

Here is the youtube link:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PN0fkr2XoCM